# ASP.NET C# Validating username and password

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, validation

Im trying to validate username and password from an MySql server. Login validation is working, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the "Create new user" validation isn't working.

Here are the code for registering new user. What happens is;

```
catch (Exception)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Brukernavnet er allerede i bruk";
    }
```

Seems like this part ^ is ruining it for me somehow, whenever i test run this code I get this message.

```
protected void newBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String cs = "Database=trafikkskole; User=user; Password=password";
        MySqlConnection dbconnect = new MySqlConnection(cs);

        try
        {

            dbconnect.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (@un, @pw)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", inputUser.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", inputPw.Text);
            cmd.Connection = dbconnect;
            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (a > 0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Gratulerer! Du har nå laget en bruker!";
            }

            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "ERROR";
            }

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Brukernavnet er allerede i bruk";
        }

        finally
        {
            dbconnect.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

If I try it like this:

```
protected void newBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String cs = "Database=trafikkskole; User=root; Password=root";
        MySqlConnection dbconnect = new MySqlConnection(cs);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dbconnect);
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
        ds = new DataSet("TEST");
        da.Fill(ds, "user");
        Response.Write(ds.Tables["user"].Rows.Count);     

        try
        {

            dbconnect.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (@un, @pw)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", inputUser.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", inputPw.Text);
            cmd.Connection = dbconnect;
            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (a > 0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Gratulerer! Du har nå laget en bruker!";
            }

            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "ERROR";
            }

        }



        catch (Exception Exception)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Brukernavnet er allerede i bruk";

        }

        finally
        {
            dbconnect.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

This ends up with the possibility of making a user without username or password.

Comment: Can you please edit with your exception logs. Such as `catch (Exception ex)
 { Debug.Writeline(ex.ToString()); }`

Comment: If you are trying to catch the result of the insert, instead of putting `int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` try with `int a = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: @amarnath
The only thing I could produce is this:

CS0169 The field 'login.da' is never used.
CS0169 The field 'login.ds' is never used.
CS0169 The field 'login.cb' is never used.

Comment: @Flxtr I tried the ExecuteScalar(); and ended up with this:

CS0266 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Sure, the result of a `ExecuteScalar();`  returns a string, this should be convert to int, one way is using `int a = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: I'm sorry, Where did you declare your "cmd" variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for trying, found a working solution, will post it here for future reference.

```
protected void newBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
        String cs = "Database=trafikkskole; User=root; Password=root";
        MySqlConnection dbconnect = new MySqlConnection(cs);

        try
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputUser.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputPw.Text))
            {
                dbconnect.Open();
                Label1.Text = "Gratulerer! Du har nå laget en bruker!";
                string qry = "INSERT INTO user(username, password) VALUES (@un, @pw)";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, dbconnect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", inputUser.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", inputPw.Text);
                cmd.Connection = dbconnect;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "ERROR";
            }

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Brukernavnet er allerede i bruk";

        }


        finally
        {
            dbconnect.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be going wrong. You should examine the exception.message to get insights as to what it could be.

For example, put a break point in the catch statement and see if the exception thrown for things like... does the username already exist and SQL is throwing an error. ... or are the username/password null, too long, etc...

Regardless, change the catch statement to `catch(Exception exception)` and see what the exception is.

Comment: The database only have one user currently, and this message pops up regardless of what I type.

Comment: This is what happens:

CS0168 C# The variable 'Exception' is declared but never used

Comment: I think that's not an Error message, that's a warning message.